# RecoilJS RecoilRoot not accessible within ThreeJS Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, recoiljs

Hoping someone can help me out here.
Im quite new to RecoilJS so if Im missing something obvious, please let me know.

I am trying to manage the state of 3D objects in a scene with RecoilJS Atoms.
I have an atom for the last item the mouse hovered over and I want to show a debug panel with its info.
For some reason the RecoilRoot provider doesn't seem to be accessible from within the ThreeJS canvas.

In Viewer (code below), I get an error warning me that `This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component` when I try to declare `const [hoveredLED, setHoveredLEDAtom] = useRecoilState(hoveredLEDAtom);` (full trace below)

However, passing `setHoveredLEDAtom` down from the parent (Viewer) works.

Declaring it within Debug also works, which is a sibling of Canvas sharing the same contexts

This is fine for now, but the whole point of moving to Recoil was to stop passing props up and down.

Am I missing something obvious or does the ThreeJS canvas somehow exist in a different scope.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

## index.js

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <RecoilRoot>
    <App />
  </RecoilRoot>
  // </React.StrictMode>
```

## App.js

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Viewer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Viewer

```js
const LED = ({ led }) => {
  const [hovered, setHoevered] = useState(false);
  const [hoveredLED, setHoveredLEDAtom] = useRecoilState(hoveredLEDAtom);

  const handleHoverEnter = () => {
    setHoveredLEDAtom(led);
    setHoevered(true);
  };
  const handleHoverExit = () => {
    setHoevered(false);
  };

  return (
    <mesh
      onPointerOver={(event) => handleHoverEnter()}
      onPointerOut={(event) => handleHoverExit()}
    >
      <coneGeometry />
      <meshStandardMaterial
        color={hovered || led.brightness > 125 ? "hotpink" : "grey"}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

```
const Debug = () => {
  const [hoveredLED, setHoveredLEDAtom] = useRecoilState(hoveredLEDAtom);
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ position: "absolute", left: "10px", top: "1rem" }}>
        member : {hoveredLED.member}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Viewer = () => {
  const [model, setModel] = useRecoilState(modelAtom);
  const [hoveredLED, setHoveredLEDAtom] = useRecoilState(hoveredLEDAtom);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(hoveredLED);
  }, [hoveredLED]);

  return (
    <>
      <Debug />
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [5, 7, 5] }} style={{ height: "700px" }}>
        <Helpers />
        <OrbitControls />
        {model.map((led, index) => {
          const key = `led-${index}`;
          return (
            <LED key={key} led={led} />
          );
        })}
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```

## Error

```
995 react-reconciler.development.js:9747 The above error occurred in the <LED> component:

    at LED (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205:5)
    at Suspense
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1998:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3860:5)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
logCapturedError @ react-reconciler.development.js:9747
2 react-three-fiber.esm.js:141 Uncaught Error: This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component.
    at err (recoil.js:16:1)
    at Object.notInAContext (recoil.js:4092:1)
    at updateRetainCount (recoil.js:3255:1)
    at useRetain_ACTUAL (recoil.js:4669:1)
    at useRetain (recoil.js:4627:1)
    at useRecoilValueLoadable (recoil.js:5234:1)
    at useRecoilValue (recoil.js:5258:1)
    at useRecoilState (recoil.js:5306:1)
    at LED (Viewer.js:76:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-reconciler.development.js:7363:1)
react-dom.development.js:18525 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component:

    at Canvas (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4179:5)
    at Viewer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:325:83)
    at div
    at App
    at RecoilRoot_INTERNAL (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:91093:5)
    at RecoilRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:91259:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18525
react-dom.development.js:26740 Uncaught Error: This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component.
    at err (recoil.js:16:1)
    at Object.notInAContext (recoil.js:4092:1)
    at updateRetainCount (recoil.js:3255:1)
    at useRetain_ACTUAL (recoil.js:4669:1)
    at useRetain (recoil.js:4627:1)
    at useRecoilValueLoadable (recoil.js:5234:1)
    at useRecoilValue (recoil.js:5258:1)
    at useRecoilState (recoil.js:5306:1)
    at LED (Viewer.js:76:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-reconciler.development.js:7363:1)
three.module.js:26599 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From :
https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilBridgeAcrossReactRoots/

> If a nested React root is created with ReactDOM.render(), or a nested
> custom renderer is used, React will not propagate context state to the
> child root. This hook is useful if you would like to "bridge" and
> share Recoil state with a nested React root. The hook returns a React
> component which you can use instead of  in your nested
> React root to share the same consistent Recoil store state. As with
> any state sharing across React roots, changes may not be perfectly
> synchronized in all cases.

So bridging the contexts is a simple as creating a bridge and nesting it within the ThreeJS Canvas

```js
const Viewer = () => {
  const RecoilBridge = useRecoilBridgeAcrossReactRoots_UNSTABLE();
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas>
        <RecoilBridge>
            ...
        </RecoilBridge>
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```